# after linking to font Awesome link works well if i use @font_face but if not it shows a weird link. i cannot seem to understand the problem

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-family

i am trying to add an icon from font_awesome
i followed the manual and took the link tag to the libary from https://cdnjs.com/
i have some old code defining specific certain icons using @font_face , which in turn defines the font-family:'FontAwesome'.
i am using my class :: before and the doc tag /"doc_tag" in content property
when i use font-family: FontAwesome (which are some old icons which i defines and in case has the one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sUs3.png)
i need for now) it works but when i use
font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free" , as instructed in the manual it does not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GEFq.png)
i saw tutorials which did the same and it worked for them (without using @font_face)

- i followed the instruction
- i checked that the libarary link tag is valid

what am i doing wrong?

i defined my library link :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

and my relevant class (to which the before will apply to her content) :

```
<p class="last-paragraph">real time embedded engineer </p>
```

and at my css file :

```
.last-paragraph::before {
    /*  font-family: "font awesome 6 free";*/
    font-weight: 500;
    content: "\f08c"; /*f08c*/
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    /*  text-transform: none !important;*/
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
/*  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";*/
}
```

with --font-family: FontAwesome-- it works well and with --font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free"-- it does not.

i will appreciate the help

Comment: The 'linkedIn' icon resides in the 'Brands' branche of *Font Awesome*, therefore you need to use `font-family: var(--fa-style-family-brands)` for version 6(?) and up...